# Use cases for std::add_const and similar

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Some type transformations in `<type_traits>` can also be expressed using core language syntax (e.g. `std::add_const<T>::type` is/seems equivalent to `const T`). Dtto for `std::add_lvalue_reference`, and perhaps others. What is the use for these type traits?

I fully understand the standard would be providing an "incomplete toolbox" without them, and I can imagine use in a meta way, something like this:

```
template<typename In, template <typename> class Modifier>
struct Apply {
  typedef typename Modifier<T>::type Out;
};

Apply<int, std::add_const>
```

Are there any other use cases for these traits which can be expressed syntactically, or are they just included "out of a sense of completeness" and for the occasional meta-use?

Comment: What happens if `T` is already `const`?

Comment: @PeterWood [Works fine](http://ideone.com/mhY62n), at least in gcc 4.7.2

Comment: @PeterWood If it's already qualified, it gives the same type back, as required by the standard.

Comment: @PeterWood In my example on ideone, there's also `B<const int>` which defines `TT` and `const T`.

Comment: @PeterWood, it does the same as `add_const`, what's your point?

Comment: The reason for `std::add_{l,r}value_reference` is that `void` would error out on a naive `T&` or `T&&`, since you can't form a reference to `void`. As for `add_const`, I can only imagine symmetry.

Comment: Concerning `add_const`, also see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135859/why-use-stdadd-const)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those traits come from Boost and the proposal to add them to the standard, [N1345](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1345.html), quotes Andrei Alexandrescu as saying:

> "I understand the symmetry argument for adding `add_const`, `add_volatile`, `add_cv`, and `add_pointer`, however I would argue in favor of eliminating them. The language-provided equivalents are just simpler and nicer."

The same proposal also gives this rationale:

> Author's Note: superficially the add_const, add_volatile and add_cv classes are irrelevant, since, for example, add_const::type is the same as T const, for all T (currently this does not apply to function types - but [issue 295](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#295) addresses this). However the experience from boost is that several users have asked for these templates to be present in the library for the following reasons: (a) Some users find these more explicit - when combining transformation templates in particular, users like the kind of "built in documentation" that these templates provide. (b) Not all users are aware that cv-qualifying a reference is allowed and has no effect, or that cv-qualifying a type that is already cv-qualified is allowed and has no effect. (c) Compilers may emit warnings when cv-qualifying a type that is a reference, or already has a cv-qualifier, these templates can be implemented such that these messages are suppressed in these cases.

Also, for `add_reference` (renamed to `add_lvalue_reference` in the standard):

> Author's Note: the add_reference template was one of the original motivations behind the boost type traits library. However the resolution to [issue 106](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#106) makes the template appear largely redundant. In spite of that add_reference may well be useful in suppressing compiler warnings when inadvertently creating references to references in template code.

Comment: `add_{l,r}value_reference` also plays nicely with `void`.

Answer (score 8):

These traits are provided for occasional meta-use. It makes it possible to transport wanted cv-qualifiers around in meta programming.

```
template<class T,template<class> class Trait>
struct transform
{
  /* working with T creating newT*/

  typedef Trait<newT>::type type;
};

template<class T>
struct special_transform
  : transfrom<T, std::add_const>
{};
```

In this case you could not replace `std::add_const` with `const`.

Comment: In this case you wouldn't yeah, because you have especially crafted this to go side-by-side with the type traits. However, what if you passed `const T` in place of `std::add_const` removing the second template parameter all together? I believe it would work in this case.

Answer (score 7):

`add_const` can be used to resolve type deduction conflicts.

```
template <typename T>
class wrapper;

template <typename T>
bool operator==(wrapper<T> const& w, T const& t);
```

Problems arise if we use `wrapper<T const>`:

```
wrapper<int const> w = { 42 };
assert(w == 42); // Error: conflicting deduced types
```

`T` is simultaneously deduced to be both `int` *and* `int const`. This can be resolved using `add_const`:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(wrapper<T> const& w, add_const_t<T>& t);
```

Comment: Interesting use case. Anything else that would make the second function parameter a non-deduced context would work too, but this one's quite concise.

Answer (score 1):

The only use case I know is illustrated below:

```
struct F
{
    bool f() const { return true; }
    bool f() { return false; }
};
assert(!F{}.f())
assert(std::add_const_t< F >{}.f());
```

It also needed for testing of *cv-ref-qualified* member-functions functionality, that may differs for different overloadings (only for lref-qualified modern C++ has handy `std::as_const` function):

```
struct F
{
    int g() & { return 1; }
    int g() const & { return 2; }
    int g() && { return 3; }
    int g() const && { return 4; }
};
F f;
assert(f.g() == 1);
assert(std::as_const(f).g() == 2);
assert(F{}.g() == 3);
assert(std::add_const_t< F >{}.g() == 4); // rarely needed, but if needed, then it helps
```