# std::add_pointer vs classic pointer

Tags: pointers, c++11

I just discovered the existence in C++ 11 of `std::add_pointer`.
I had a look at the documentation at the following link but i do not really get the purpose of such an object:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/add_pointer/

- What is the main difference between for instance `std::add_pointer<int>` and a classic pointer ie `int*`?
- How do you deference such a pointer? (do you use`::value`?)
- what does add stand for?

Comment: You might be interested in this [question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435170/use-cases-for-stdadd-const-and-similar).

Comment: That's useful in metaprogramming, i.e. when writing function templates which do not know about exact types.

Comment: @el.pescado can you make me a small example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type=typename Tag::Type;

template<template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class Test, class T>
struct apply_if:
  std::conditional_t< Test<T>{}, tag_t<Z<T>>, tag_t<T> >
{};
template<template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class Test, class T>
using apply_if_t = type<apply_if<Z,Test,T>>;
```

this takes a metafunction `Z` and a test `Test` and a type `T`, and returns `Z<T>` if the `Test<T>` is true, and otherwise returns `T`.

You cannot pass `just put a * after the type` to `apply_if_t` as `Z`.  You can pass `std::add_pointer` or `add_pointer_t`.

Suppose you want to add pointers only if something is a function type (like `int(int)`).  Then `apply_if_t< std::add_pointer_t, std::is_function, X >` will be `X*` if `X` is a function type, and `X` if not.

`std::add_pointer<T>::type` is to `T*` as `int inc(int x){return x+1;}` is to `x+1`.

Comment: `add_pointer` also play nicely with references and (since an LWG issue) crazy function types. The former is fairly handy with forwarding references.