# std::add_const_t<T>& vs const T&

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

The cppreference about [`as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) states that a possible implementation of this function is

```
template <class T>
constexpr std::add_const_t<T>& as_const(T& t) noexcept
{
    return t;
}
```

Wouldn't it be a bit more straightforward to write the following?

```
template <class T>
constexpr const T& as_const(T& t) noexcept
{
    return t;
}
```

I've seen preferential use of similar traits in situations in which it would be just as easy (or easier) to use keywords instead.
This makes me wonder, is there a difference between the two function definitions? Is there some kind of portability issue or something else the first definition using the type trait avoids? If I'm writing a template library, should I use the first approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435170/use-cases-for-stdadd-const-and-similar

Comment: Yup, that answers it. I suppose, concerning specifically the function in question, the trait could suppress a potential warning, as stated in the accepted answer.